# Provisioning Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant with Ansible fails on chown

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

I am trying to provision an Ubuntu Xenial Vagrant guest with Ansible. It worked correctly on Ubuntu 14.04, but fails on 16.04. The error that I get is

`chown failed: failed to look up user vagrant`

The task that I am running is the following:

`- name: Ensure /srv/web exists
  become: yes
  file:
    path: /srv/web
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: "{{ remote_user }}"`

Searching hasn't found much help.

Thanks!

Edit: Further testing on a Digital Ocean 14.04 droplet also shows this issue.

Edit 2: [Full output log](https://gist.github.com/zuhairp/dc6543e8cc470ba8cab8e69fc5dca6c6) at -vvvv level

Comment: Maybe this has got something to do with the particular image that you are working with.

Comment: I've also run into this same exact issue with a digital ocean 14.04 image.  I'll update my question

Comment: You can use the "Bento Boxes" instead -- the bento ubuntu boxes come with a 'vagrant' user, which is more typical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLOUTION#1**

Ubuntu 16.04 has python3, not 2.7.x. and Ansible doesn't support for Python 3 yet.

For Ubuntu 16.04 I use the following play to get Python 2.7 installed.

```
---
- hosts: xenials 
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install python 2.7 
      raw: apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qq python2.7

    - name: check if softlink exists
      stat:
        path: /usr/bin/python
      register: python_file

    - name: create softlink for python 2.7
      raw: ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
      when: python_file.stat.islnk is not defined

    - name: Ensure /srv/web exists
      file:
        path: /srv/web
        state: directory
        mode: 0755
        owner: "{{ remote_user }}" # hope you have defined this variable in your ansible.cfg
```

key line is `gather_facts: no` which prevents Ansible to execute code on the remote server that the remote server cannot yet support.Without this line,play would fail.

That provides an `/usr/bin/python2.7`, which I explicitly point to in my inventory file.

```
[xenials] 
192.168.33.100 

[xenials:vars] 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Note that there is nothing special about the name `xenials`. It's just a group I have defined in my inventory.

This `ansible_python_interpreter` only need for the first time, after that you can remove it because we have created the softlink for the python2.7
Hope that help you.

**SOLOUTION#2**

**Reason of this error:**

I have reviewed the gist that contain the detail log and figured out this:

- I am sure you are using the official vagrant box `ubuntu/xenial64`
- This official vagrant box doesn't have `vagrant` user
  [image]
- `"msg": "chown failed: failed to look up user vagrant"` that's the error trace which help you find the exact error.

**Solution-1 to this error:**

Download some other vagrant box, I recommend this vagrant box `geerlingguy/ubuntu1604` it has really good reputation

**Solution-2 to this error:**

With the official vagrant box, you can do the same as I am doing to mitigate this error. Add the following to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    ssh_user = ENV['USER']
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" #{ssh_user}
      mkdir -p /home/#{ssh_user}/.ssh
      touch /home/#{ssh_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
      chown -R #{ssh_user}. /home/#{ssh_user}/.ssh
      echo "#{ssh_user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/99-#{ssh_user}
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/#{ssh_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
      chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/99-#{ssh_user}
    SHELL
  end
```

What it will do is, just create your host login user to the guest and upload the rsa key for it. So you can run the playbook to the vagrant machine as if it is the remote machine. If you'll face any problem further, please let me know.

Hope this help you.

Comment: increase the verbosity and paste the error in your question please

Comment: I have added a gist with the full output to the question

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error for vagrant. As for digital ocean, i had a comma in my variables file so it was looking for "username," instead of "username"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am using `ubuntu/xenial64`.

I noticed that there is no `vagrant` user. When I SSH in using Vagrant, the `ubuntu` user is used.

I created an `ansible.cnf`:

```
[default]
remote_user = ubuntu
```

After that I encountered another issue: no python. I fixed this with:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Now, the `ansible ping` module works for my host.

```
$ ansible elastichsearch -m ping
192.168,101.10 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```