# Unable to connect to ubuntu 16.04 using ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ansible playbook to create new AWS EC2 instance. I am running my playook from host1 and then want to run some tasks on newly created EC2 instance (host2). I am able to run all the ansible tasks if my EC2 ubuntu is 14.04 but it fails on ping if i change to ubuntu 16.04. I get below error when trying ping from host1  `ansible host2 -m ping`

```
 "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python2.7: not found\r\n",
```

I see couple of places it is mentioned that ubuntu 16.04 comes with python 3 and ansible does not support 3 yet hence we need to install ansible 2.7. My confusion is how can i installed python on my EC2 instance when ansible is failing to connect at the first place it self.

Any idea how can i around this?

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Connect to it and install it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provisioning Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant with Ansible fails on chown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802230/provisioning-ubuntu-16-04-vagrant-with-ansible-fails-on-chown)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "raw" module to bootstrap the systems with Python 2.x.

e.g:

```
ansible host2 --sudo -m raw -a "apt-get install -y python2.7 python-simplejson"
```

Documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html

http://serverascode.com/2016/08/16/ansible-python2-xenial.html

If your repositories don't have 2.7 you can install it from the deadsnakes repo, just add this ppa;

```
ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
```